# troubles using the glsl barrier() function in a vulkan compute shader on Adreno 630

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan, compute-shader

I am developping a rendering application using vulkan on a Adreno 630 GPU (the platform is SDM845).

I tried using a compute shader to pre-process some of my attachments, but I have trouble using the barrier() function to synchronize my threads.

Anywhere I add the "barrier();" instruction, It makes my application crash.

I compile the glsl code using glslangvalidator to generate spir-v compiled code for my compute shader.

The version of glslangvalidator  I use is:

```
>glslangvalidator -v
Glslang Version: 7.11.3113
ESSL Version: OpenGL ES GLSL 3.20 glslang Khronos. 11.3113
GLSL Version: 4.60 glslang Khronos. 11.3113
SPIR-V Version 0x00010300, Revision 6
GLSL.std.450 Version 100, Revision 1
Khronos Tool ID 8
SPIR-V Generator Version 7
GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl version 100
ARB_GL_gl_spirv version 100
```

The "barrier();" instruction is not included into conditional code, so it should work.

Even if I start the main function with the "barrier();" instruction, it makes my application crash:

Example of glsl code I tried:

```
#version 460
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable

void main()
{
    // some variables declarations

    barrier();

    *** my code ***

}
```

But if I comment the line with barrier(), my application doesn't crash anymore.

---

As barriers work when I use OpenCL on the same hardware, I tried to workaround the issue by using clspv.

I checked out the latest master code from this repo:
https://github.com/google/clspv/blob/master/docs/OpenCLCOnVulkan.md

I successfully compiled some basic OpenCL C code into spir-v, but when I add barriers to the code (barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);), I encounter the same issue.

Any hint on what could be wrong or anybody having experienced the same issue?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug. You can try reporting it to the OEM. Also check for OTA updates for your device: it sounds like you probably have an older driver as I know code using barriers has worked on Adreno 6xx drivers for a while now.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was indeed suspecting a driver/hardware issue. I am using the libvulkan.so library provided in the latest downloadable Adreno Vulkan SDK 1.05: [link](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/adrenosdk/adreno-sdk-vulkan.zip?referrer=node/6114).

Comment: I have already posted a comment in Qualcomm Developer Network forum, but I have unfortunately had no reply.